How to get headings and sub headings for the user query along with the answer?
Im creating a generative chat bot in GCP with agend builder and Dialogflow cx.
The chat bot is giving good response. But I want the chat bot to get the headings and sub headings of the user query along with the answer or response or user query.
I tried adding parameters in the chat section.
I also tried approaching various features like Genearative Fallback, Fulfillment and prompts

If possible please add the documentation you are following.
